# Push to Heroku fails: Could not find net-ssh-2.10.0 in any of the sources. Failed to install gems via Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, deployment, bundler

I tried pushing my app to heroku but get the following error:

```
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.2
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Could not find net-ssh-2.10.0 in any of the sources
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Could not find net-ssh-2.10.0 in any of the sources
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

What can I do about this?

I've removed Gemfile.lock to see if rebuilding this file would make a difference, but it didn't. Also, I've tried `gem uninstall net-ssh-2.10.0` and then `bundle install` before pushing to heroku. Also, I removed `fog` from my Gemfile since that's the gem with which `net-ssh-2.10.0` comes along; then did `bundle update`, `gem cleanup`, put `fog` back in the Gemfile, ran `bundle install`, pushed to git, and pushed to heroku with again the same result.

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby                  '2.2.2'
gem 'rails',          '4.2.3'
gem 'bcrypt',         '3.1.10'
gem 'faker',          '1.4.3'
gem 'carrierwave',    '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',    '4.2.9'
gem 'fog',            '1.32.0'
gem 'aws-sdk',        '2.1.11'
gem 'sass-rails',     '5.0.3'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '3.3.5.1'
gem 'uglifier',       '2.7.1'
gem 'coffee-rails',   '4.1.0'
gem 'wice_grid',      '3.5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails', '1.4.0'
gem 'friendly_id',    '5.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',   '4.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks',     '2.5.3'
gem 'jbuilder',       '2.3.1'
gem 'sdoc',           '0.4.1', group: :doc
gem 'pg',             '0.18.2'

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor',     '0.0.3'
  gem 'puma',               '2.11.2'
end
```

Comment: Have you tried adding "net-ssh" to your Gemfile?

Comment: I added `gem 'net-ssh', '2.10.0'` to my gemfile, ran `bundle install`, pushed to git and then pushed to heroku. Unfortunately, I got the same error message.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that this [version](https://rubygems.org/gems/net-ssh/versions/2.10.0) just has been removed from Rubygems...
May we have to do a downgrade or an upgrade...

The cause of deletion is [here](https://github.com/net-ssh/net-ssh/issues/260).

Comment: Thanks! I had to delete Gemfile.lock, added `gem 'net-ssh', '2.10.0.beta2'` to my Gemfile, ran `bundle install`, pushed to git and then pushed to heroku. This solved it. I don't really know how to interpret the versions either, so I don't know whether it is good sense to use the version I choose.

Answer (score 8):

Add to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'net-ssh', '!= 2.10.0'
```

And run:

```
bundle update net-ssh
```

Comment: Thanks, that works perfectly. It then (at this moment) picks `net-ssh 2.9.2`.