# Heroku staging enviroment. Failed to install gems via Bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, bundler

I'd like to make staging environment on Heroku, besides production environment. I've prepared stating env as following.

```
heroku create odai-staging --remote staging
heroku config:add RACK_ENV=staging RAILS_ENV=staging --remote staging
```

On Gemfile, a group of staging is prepared.

```
group :production, :staging do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Then, do as follows.

```
bundle install 

git push staging master
```

However, I've got following errors. How should I do? I'm looking forward to hearing from you.

```
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path     vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment 
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Could not find net-ssh-2.10.0 in any of the sources
remote:        Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from    https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Could not find net-ssh-2.10.0 in any of the sources
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
```

Comment: check out this thread, i think it will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31793791/push-to-heroku-fails-could-not-find-net-ssh-2-10-0-in-any-of-the-sources-faile

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it now.

Comment: It has not solved the problem. I'll keep on searching another solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem doing as follows! Thank your for your help!

```
gem 'net-ssh', '!= 2.10.0'
bundle update
```